# How to skip one activity while sending back data using intents?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Consider I've 3 activities  Activity1 Activity2   Activity3 if I want to send back data to Activity1 from Activity3 skipping Activity2 what should I do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a "correct" way to this adding **FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT** to the intent.
Which is used to start the next activity and notify it to pass the result to the first one:

**Code:**

```
Activity 1 -> startActivityForResult(activityB,0);
Activity 2 -> activityCintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT);
              startActivity(activityCintent); finish();
Activity 3 -> setresult(10); finish();
Activity 1 -> if(result==10) {dofunction(); }
```

Comment: I'm sorry for updating status very late. But this is best answer that I can carry out. Thank you @Nir Duan

Comment: What in case if user wanted to go back to Activity B. Any suggestion !!

Comment: "Which **is used** to start". I read it as "Which **used** to" and thought I was out of luck because it had been depreciated. Please correct this.

Comment: Fixed (there is minimum comment character number)

Answer (score 2):

Restarting of activity1 again is not a good way.

You can achieve this using "startActivityForResult"

Use below code, to start Activity2

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Activity2.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

Use below code, to start Activity3

`Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Activity3.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);`

In activity3 use the below code where you want to send the data to activity1:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
        intent.putExtra("Key", value);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
```

Override onActivityResult in Activity1 and Activity2.

In onActivityResult of activity2,check the request code and Result code. Based on this call finish(), and set the values as below :

```
 boolean value = data.getBooleanExtra("key, false);

 Intent intent = getIntent();
            intent.putExtra("Key", Value);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
```

In onActivityResult of activity1 you will get the data.

Comment: I would recommend using the built-in FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT

Comment: Yes, you are right and sorry for late update. @NirDuan

Answer (score 0):

If you dont think just sending data restart Activity 1 with data you wanna send within intent.